# Connecting to SQL Server at ISP over the Internet using Sql Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

How do I do this?  The ISP says it's possible, but there's no place in the connection dialog for an IP address.  Will it not work with the Express version; do I need the full version of SSMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes instead of Server name put server IP. Also for express SQL edition, remote connections need to be enabled. (They are not by default).
However no such issue with the Management Studio (Be it Full or Express)

Answer (score 1):

Where you enter the "server name" you can enter a URL to the server you want to connect too.

Comment: It was the IP.  Thanks for the tip.